# Prove: $T \in L(V, V)$ then $ \exists S \in L(V,V)$ such that $ST = 0 \iff T$ is not onto

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove: $T \in L(V, V)$ then $ \exists S \in L(V,V)$ such that $ST = 0 \iff T$ is not onto

Proof: $\rightarrow$

Let $S \in L(V,V)$ s.t $S \neq 0$ and $ST = 0$. Consider $S(T(v))$ for some $v\in V$
Then $T=0$ and we have $S(T(v)) = S(0) = 0. \iff$ is not one to one$\iff T$ is not onto

1. Is this correct so far?
2. I need help with the other direction
3. I think I can just take the reverse steps if this is correct

Comment: Why must $T(v) = 0$? Just because $S\neq 0$ doesn't mean that $S(v) = 0 \implies v=0$.

Comment: The implication is false, since if $S=0$ then $ST=0$ whether or not $T$ is onto.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments your proof is not convincing. To answer the other questions, let me give you some hints:

**Hint 1:** Prove that if $T$ is onto, then there does not exist such an $S$. I think this is easier since now you can apply the definition of onto meaning that for each $w$ there exists $v$ with $Tv=w$. Now you have $0=STv=Sw$. What can you conclude?

**Hint 2:** If $T$ is not onto, think about block matrices, or taking a complement of a certain choice of a subspace of $V$ and then define $S$ on each of the direct summands with the easiest possible choice.